# I have no internet connection after upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, networking, upgrade

I upgraded Ubuntu to 12.10. It seemed to work fine, except that I get no response from Internet.

```
sent ping 8.8.8.8
reply  icmp_req=112 ttl=47 time=27.6 (mnimum time, max time 30.5)
```

How can this be repaired?

Comment: could you give us the output of sudo ifconfig, please

Comment: [sudo] eth0 Link encap:Etheernet HWaddr 60:eb69:5a:b3:39 inet addr:81.166.77.43 Bcast:81.166.77.255 Mask:255.255.255.0 inet6 addr: fe80::62eb:69ff.fe5a:b339/64 Scope:Link UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU.15500 Metric:1 RX packets:16 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns0 carrier:0 collitions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:1676 (1.6 KB) TX bytes :9707 (9.1 KB) Interrupt:16

Comment: What's in your /etc/network/interface s file?

Comment: there is no file /etc/network/interface!   But sudo had TX packet:39 err0rs 10 etc  Gunnar

Comment: There should be a file in /etc/network called interfaces.  This file is responsible for network connection from the start.

Comment: /etc/network/interfaces  auto lo  iface lo inet loopback    gunnar

Comment: file: etc/network/interfaces=> auto lo (new line) iface lo inet loopback

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a dhcp server as most modernrouters got replace the contetn of that file with

```
#This file describe the network interfaces available on your system
#and how to activate them. For more information see interfaces(5).

#The loopack network interface 

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#The primary network interface 

auto eth0 
iface inet dhcp
```

and reboot. This should fix it!

Comment: Changed the file interfaces as you wrote, except that there some extra empty lines which i could not get rid of. i think it is 10-15 years since i used the vi-editor. Loged out of Ubuntu, loged in - go messages 1) Waiting for network connection.  after a while 2) Booting system without full network configuration. nothing more happened, next morning message 2 was still on the screen. switched off and on again, wrote password - nothing more happened. Is it easier to load down 13.04 fom Windows  Gunnar

Comment: You don't have to do that.  Just  biot up again.  Wait 2nminutes until Plymouth doesn't display the message and gi to an other console by pressing ALT + F3 login at this console and edit your interface file again.   Tell me something about your network confg

Comment: Ip of your router netmask and so on.

Comment: I was not abel to do anything! GNU GRUB screen came up
Chosed Ubuntu Linux 3.5.39 ->black screen, after 1 min (?) the screen got a little lighter. after some minutes switched off, tried Linux 3.2.52 -> same result.
Tried recovery mode -> initctl: Event failed
Waiting for network configuration
I am connected to Altibox fibre optic network via Residental Access Gateway from Telsy telecomunications

Comment: This sounds more like a unusable kernel and not like a network problem. You should consider a re installation and saveing your data with a live cd